# add-windowsfeature is not recognized

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, exception

I'm trying to run powershell commands using C# but I keep getting errors when I invoke the pipeline. I was wondering if anyone know why I keep getting add-windowsfeature is not recognized.  Thanks in advance.

```
private static void RunScript(string name)
{
    InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initial.ImportPSModule(new[] { "ServerManager"});
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial); 
    // create Powershell runspace

    runspace.Open();

    RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
    runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");


    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    Command cm = new Command("Import-module");
    cm.Parameters.Add("name","ServerManager");
    pipeline.Commands.Add(cm);
    Command command = new Command("add-windowsfeature"); 
    command.Parameters.Add(null, name);  
    pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

    var a = pipeline.Invoke();
    foreach (var psObject in a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(psObject);
    }

    runspace.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the ServerManager module is being imported properly. Can you try executing the `import-module` command before you try the `add-windowsfeature` and see the result it gives?

Comment: I tried the following..but the same error.  RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvokerImport = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            runSpaceInvokerImport.Invoke("Import-module ServerManager");

Comment: There is no new error.  Same error on line Command command = new Command("add-windowsfeature"); 
saying it is not a valid cmdlet.  I'm starting to think that I should include the full path of add-windowsfeature....

Comment: Temporarily replace your add-windowsfeature invocation with "Get-Module" to verify you have the correct module(s) loaded.  Does ServerManager have a dependency on another module that might not be available?

Comment: @Zuzlx I ment what does it say when you execute the command to import it. You should be able to read output along the lines of 'Module has been successfully loaded' You need to verify this before you continue on to the add-windowsfeature or you will keep getting the same result.

Comment: another thing I would do first is make sure you can import it using powershell directly. What OS are you using? This shows Server 2008, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff476071.aspx. I tried it on a Server 2012 box and it works as well but does not work on Windows 7/8

Comment: First off, thank you guys for taking a look.  I replaced the "add-windowsfeature" with Get-Module and, while it didn't throw an exception, the list was empty.  So no errors - but Get-module returns an empty set.  Running the sequence in the shell windows works. I'm on Windows 2008 R2 sp1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerManager is a 64-bit only module (it doesn't exist under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` but will exist under `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`). Compile as x64 and your code should work.

Comment: thanks.  Yup it was a 64 v 32 issue if I remember correctly.  Marked as answered.